# Why is my PHP query executing twice on page load?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am newish to PHP and I seem to be having an issue with an insert statement that executes twice when I open this page to view a document. The document shows with no error. In the database the 2nd insert is 1 second later. It happens in google chrome only and on this page only. IE has no issue, I dont have firefox to check.

**view_document.php**

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../includes/core.php');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../includes/connect.php');

$webusername = $_SESSION['webname'];

if (isset($_GET['document']))
{
    $ainumber = (int) $_GET['document'];

    if (!ctype_digit($_GET['document']) || !preg_match('~^[0-9]+$~', $_GET['document']) || !is_numeric($_GET['document']))
    {
        $_SESSION = array();
        session_destroy();
        header('Location: login.php');
    }
    else
    {
        $stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT s_filename, s_reference FROM dmsmain WHERE s_ainumber = ?") or die(mysqli_error());

        $stmt->bind_param('s', $ainumber);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($filename, $reference);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();

        $file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../dms/files/' . $filename . '.pdf';

        if (file_exists($file))
        {
            header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
            header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=' . basename($file));
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
            header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
            readfile($file);

            $stmt = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO dmslog (s_reference, s_userid, s_lastactivity,    s_actiontype) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)") or die(mysqli_error());

            date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Johannesburg');
            $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $actiontype = 'DL';

            $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $reference, $webusername, $date, $actiontype);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
        }
        else
        {
            $missing = "<b>File not found</b>";
        }
            exit(0); // Correct Place?
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="../CSS/dms.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<title>Denso Document Manager - View Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td width="28%"><img src="../images/Logo.gif"/></td>
<td width="43%"><h2 style="color:#666" align="left">Denso SA Document Management System</h2></td>
<td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="25%" align="right"><?php echo "Welcome $webusername <input class=\"look\" type=\"button\" onclick=\"parent.location='logout.php'\" value=' Logout ' />" ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br />
<table bgcolor="#6699CC" height="30px" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td width="20%" align="center"><p style="color:#FFF"><b>Document Search</b></p></td>
<td width="20%" align="center"><p style="color:#FFF"><b>Add Document</b></p></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="content">
<?php echo $missing; ?>
<br />
<br />
</div>
<div id="footer">
<table width="100%" bgcolor="#6699CC">
<tr>
<td height="25px"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table width="100%" bgcolor="#000000">
<tr>
<td height="25px"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My HTTP access records I assume

```
[15/Nov/2012:10:14:32 +0200] "POST /dms/search.php HTTP/1.1" 200    5783 "http://www.denso.co.za/dms/search.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11"
[15/Nov/2012:10:14:33 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11"

[15/Nov/2012:10:14:34 +0200] "GET /dms/view_document.php?document=8 HTTP/1.1" 200 2965 "http://www.denso.co.za/dms/search.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11"
[15/Nov/2012:10:14:35 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11"
```

I have checked my `<img src=''>` links and I dont see a problem with them.

The records indictate there is a favicon.ico request so I created a blank favicon and placed it in my public_html folder and linked it in the page like so `<link href="../favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />`

Unfortunately that did not work as the statement still executes twice.
I am unsure if it is a favicon issue as my upload page uses an insert query and it executes once.

If someone could please tell me where I am going wrong or point me in the right direction I would be very grateful

Comment: Check your Google Chrome's `F12` developer tools menu's Network tab to see if 2 separate calls are made, and by which page.

Comment: I don't believe that the favicon issue would affect your MySQL. If you want to resolve the favicon issue for all browsers though, add the following lines to the HEAD section of the page: `<link type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">` and `<link type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" rel="icon">`

Comment: @Cthulhu I checked using the developer tools and 2 seperate calls are made by the view_document.php page. The 1st call is highlighted in red and the status is (cancelled). I assume that means the 1st call is failing for some reason?

Comment: `I don't have firefox to check` -- so *why* don't you have firefox to check? It's a free and simple download. And any web developer worth his salt should be checking his site in all the major browsers. (I'd include Safari and Opera in the list as well, and also multiple versions of IE)

Comment: That favicon 404 error may be relevant. Do you have a custom page or redirect for 404 errors that would cause the main page to load?

Comment: @SDC Thats a very valid point about the browsers and they are installing now :) I do have a redirect for 404 errors to my index.html 
`ErrorDocument 404 /index.html`

Comment: does loading the index.html cause the PHP to run? If so, you've found the problem. As for why it happens in some browsers and not others, I guess it's down to each browser as to whether it tries to load the favicon. I guess Chrome reloads it each time, whereas IE recognises that it threw a 404 once so doesn't try to load it again.

Comment: @SDC I never got redirected by a 404 error as the document displayed correctly it just seems there are 2 calls. I have linked the favicon correctly so my records dont indicate a 404 error on the favicon or anything now but I still have 2 inserts.

Comment: Do you have some AJAX running on page load?

Comment: If there is HTML on this page, look for things like empty `src` attributes in `<img>` tags, which would cause an extra HTTP request to the same script.

Comment: @infinity No AJAX or javascript on page load
@ Michael Berkowski I have checked all links and used Dreamweavers link checker and all links are okay it seems. I will post my HTML perhaps the problem is there?

Answer (score 3):

This code:

```
if (file_exists($file))
{
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=' . basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    readfile($file);

    //...
}
```

should definitely have [exit()](http://php.net/exit) call at the end of it, like so:

```
if (file_exists($file))
{
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=' . basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    readfile($file);

    //...
    exit(0);
}
```

otherwise you're first sending the file, then outputting HTML after it, causing all kinds of strange behaviour. Don't know if it's the reason, but try it.

(Also, as a principle, you'd need to serve something with code 404 if the file is not found...)

Comment: I have added the `exit(0);` in my code and no change. I added it in my code at the top here as well, is it in the right place? If the file is not found I have a variable declared `else { $missing = "<b>File not Found</b>";    }` The variable is in my HTML section which will display on the page if not found.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old question but just having same issue. It's caused by application/pdf type and the fact it opens in a browser (using chrome). If you right click and save link as, your code will be run only once

Same if you change type to any other. It's simply due to opening pdf in the browser windows. No idea for a workaround

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on previous answers and comments.....

Wordpress is causing a second page load for favicon.ico. I spotted this from the server logs, and appending the S_SERVER variable to a log file. So to put a 100% end to it I added the below code before the code I did not want to run twice (within the function in my class)

```
if (isset($_SERVER['REDIRECT_SCRIPT_URI']))
            {
                if ($_SERVER['REDIRECT_SCRIPT_URI']==="https://whaterver.yoursite.com/favicon.ico")
                    return;
            }
```

... and tada. problem gone. whaterver.yoursite.com is obviously your site url.